# minha lista switch case esta me dando um numero inesperado

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um pequena lista em c para dispensação de remédio no "case a" era para o programa me da o valor de 1, 2 ou 3, mas ela esta me dando 6487568, como posso resolver isso?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main (){
char letra;
double miligrama;
printf("Escolha uma alternativa:\n");
printf("a - Amoxicilina\n");
printf("b - Sulfametoxazol/Trimetoprina\n");
printf("c - Azitromicina\n");
scanf("%c", &letra);
switch (letra){
    case 'a':
        printf("Qual e a miligrama da sunspecao?\n");
        printf("1 - 250mg/5ml\n");
        printf("2 - 400mg/5ml\n");
        printf("3 - 500mg/5ml\n");
        scanf("%d", &miligrama);
        printf("%d", &miligrama);
        break;
    case 'b':
```

Comment: Também pudera, está usando formato `%d` com `double`, veja https://ideone.com/Ew7vSb

Comment: poste um código completo, compilável... Não use `%c` em `scanf()`. Só vai ter problemas. Teste o retorno de `scanf()` leia o manual. **Leia a linha toda** e considere a primeira letra no `switch`. O comando se chama `case`. Não existe `switch case`.

Answer (score 0):

Na função printf não precisa colocar esse "&" de endereço da variável , e é isso que está sendo mostrado , e removendo vai mostrar o valor da variável mesmo ,  mas a leitura de double no scanf é com "%f" , pois "%d" é para decimal inteiro , . ,,

```
scanf ( "%lf"      , & miligrama ); /// long float
printf( "%4.2lf\n" ,   miligrama );
```